# About React's JSX components and .map() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, jsx

Given the this  code:

```
const array = ['um', 'dois', 'tres', 'quatro', 'cinco'];

const Task = (value, i) => {
  return (
    <li key={i}>{value}</li>
  );
}


function App() {
return (
   array.map((e, i) => {
     return Task(e, i);
   })
)
}
```

I have noticed that mapping this array calling the Task() function on each element returns another array populated with objects, each one being a JSX element. So far, ok.
And that this returned array is automatically rendered by React.
So the question is: considering that arrays are lists that reference memory locations, is it right to assume that React will render JSX elements whenever they're directly declared on a variable as well if they're part of a list? I mean, React will automatically iterate through the array (and object, maybe?) and search for JSX on each array it encounters inside a render()?

Comment: jsx is not parsed by react at runtime. Typically you use babel/webpack to transpile the jsx code to regular javascript syntax (a "bundle"). The javascript is what's evaulated at runtime by react.

Comment: The react documentation shows what the jsx to javascript transpilation looks like: https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-represents-objects

Answer (score -1):

That's the case with Array lists but not with objects as I've seen. As long as they be at some Component level they'll be iterated and its components will be rendered. By the way, I'm not sure if that's the case with nested arrays, pretty sure it needs to be a flat Array or Iterable object.